# Help with Regex.Replace("GARGANO/MART/RUBI250/(FLAH)", @"\bRUB(I(N?)?)?([0-9]*)\b", "TOKE")

Tags: .net, regex

I have regular expression problem where I have to replace a word or the abbreviation of a word in a string.

Let assume that we have the string "GARGANO/MART/RUBI250/(FLAH)". 
The word in this string is RUBIN but has been abbreviated as RUBI250.

However, when I used the expression

```
Regex.Replace("GARGANO/MART/RUBI250/(FLAH)", @"\bRUB(I(N?)?)?([0-9]*)\b", "TOKE")
```

I get this
    "GARGANO/MART/TOKE/(FLAH/GENN)"

My desired result is 
    "GARGANO/MART/TOKE250/(FLAH/GENN)"

It seems like, it thinks the number is a part of the work and is replacing the number. When I change the regular expression to

@"\bRUB(I(N?)?)?\b",

then it DOES NOT return any match because I guess the number screws everything up. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
Regex.Replace("GARGANO/MART/RUBI250/(FLAH)", @"\bRUB(I(N?)?)?(?=[0-9]*\b)", "TOKE")
```

`(?=[0-9]*\b)` is a lookahead, meaning it must be there after the match, but it's not *part* of the match.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the ([0-9]*) part by its lookahead version (?=[0-9]*). It shouldn't replace the number part of your match when it exists.